# Android: Fragment state lost

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an Android application with a BottomBar which is consisted of 4 tabs which are all fragments, let's say `A, B, C, D`. While being at tab A, the user can press buttons which will open new fragments like A2, A3 etc. My problem is: after I reach A2, when I press on other tabs on the bottom bar `(B,C,D)`,  and then press back A, I turn back to fragment A instead of A2.

Is there any solution to save the current fragment (A2) when I switch back to tab A? Or shall I use seperate activities for each tab instead of fragments? I am using the `replace()` method of the `FragmentTransaction` class in order to switch between A and A2.

Comment: Are you using fragments inside fragments?  I don't really suggest that, it tends to have issues.  But if you do, are you using the childFragmentManager instead of the fragmentManager for replacement?

Comment: No, I'm swithcing from a fragment to another fragment.

Comment: In onResume in bottom tab A are you reseting up A1, A2, A3? That could be the issue.